# Reading custom metadata from Firebase storage using Kotlin (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, metadata

I'm newish to Kotlin, and new to StackOverflow. This is my first question.

I'm trying to retrieve and parse metadata stored in Google Firebase storage, using Kotlin.  I have successfully retrieved the file and displayed it, and am able to get a reference to the metadata using *val valName = referenceName.metadata*.  At this point I would like to retrieve the custom metadata that is stored in that val and parse it to a string. Printing the contents of the metadata using toString() returns com.google.android.gms.tasks.*taskId* to the console.

I've visited the docs and used them for a lot of my project so far, they are located at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata, but am stuck on what to do next.

Thanks for your help!

My code:

```
    // create an instance of the firebase storage
    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()

    // create a reference to storage
    val storageRef = storage.reference

    // create a reference to the featured content image
    val filmRef = storageRef.child("featured/film.jpg")

    // place the image metadata in a val - this appears to be working
    val filmMeta = filmRef.metadata

    // parse metadata to a string
    // ****** what to do next? ********
    val filmId = filmMeta.customMetadata("id") // <--- this does not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your customMetedata in storage ref

```
val metadata = storageMetadata {
    setCustomMetadata("id", "filmId")
}

filmRef.updateMetadata(metadata).addOnSuccessListener {
    // Updated metadata is in storageMetadata
    val filmId =  it.getCustomMetadata("id")
}.addOnFailureListener {

}
```

Then you can use like this:

```
filmRef.metadata.addOnSuccessListener {
    val filmId =  it.getCustomMetadata("id")
}.addOnFailureListener {

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly.  It was the last bit of syntax that I was in search of.